# Run PHP Script once at a specific time

Tags: php, mysql, events, time, cron

i am making some kind of a browsergame.

i have already something like "build a house" where i make a mysql event that changes the db entry for house from 5 to lets say 10 at a specific time - e.g. in 5 minutes 25 seconds.pretty easy so far.

problem is when i want to make something like a fight between 2 guys in e.g. 6 minutes 12 seconds....i have to run a php script in exactly 6min12sec that calculates their troops and the fight itself at that time and then make database changes.

i cant "pre calculate" the fight at the time the guy sent his troops to the other one cause in that 6min12secs the other guy could buy more troops or defence...

i hope u understood what im trying to do.

mysql cant run php script from events or triggers...

and running a cron job every second just to check if there is a fight happening this second is way too much serverload i guess....even if its not, most providers only allow crons every 5 minutes or maybe 2min...

is there any way to achieve what im aiming to do ?

**EDIT:**
maybe i just stay with mysql-events but i have to do alot of stuff when calculating the fight...like i.e. use random numbers, add percentages, do some queries, maybe use arrays, write messages to players...i dont think all this is possible in mysql

Comment: You're aware that 'i.e.' means 'in other words', in contrast with 'e.g.', which means 'for example'?

Comment: dont speak foreign language when youre tried i guess :D ...gonna change it thx

Comment: Well, I suppose Latin is a foreign language ;-)

Answer (score 0):

## Believe could be achieved with events

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html

## Player table

```
CREATE TABLE player (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Attack NOT NULL,
    Defense NOT NULL,
    Health NOT NULL,
    TroopCount NOT NULL
);
```

## Battle table

```
CREATE TABLE battle (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    attackerid INT NOT NULL,
    defenderid INT NOT NULL,
    desc VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    battledate DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

## CREATE EVENT statement create these in PHP application:

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS battle_001
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 6 MINUTE + INTERVAL 12 SECONDS
DO
  
  INSERT INTO battle(battledate,desc)
  # Create Select to do the math
  SELECT    NOW()
            , #replace with battle algorithm both the attacker and defender values available for the math
  
    FROM player AS attacker
    INNER Join player AS defender
     ON defender.id = #replace with defenders id
    WHERE attacker.id = #replace with attackers id
  
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

cron is great for scripts run on a regular basis, but if you want a one-off (or two-off) script to run at a particular time you would use the unix 'at' command, and you can do it directly from php using code like this:

/****
* Schedule a command using the AT command
*
* To do this you need to ensure that the www-data user is allowed to
* use the 'at' command - check this in /etc/at.deny
*
*
* EXAMPLE USAGE ::
*
* scriptat( '/usr/bin/command-to-execute', 'time-to-run');
* The time-to-run shoud be in this format: strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M", $unixtime)
*
**/

```
function scriptat( $cmd = null, $time = null ) {
    // Both parameters are required
    if (!$cmd) {
        error_log("******* ScriptAt: cmd not specified");
        return false;
    }
    if (!$time) {
        error_log("******* ScriptAt: time not specified");
        return false;
    }

    // We need to locate php (executable)
    if (!file_exists("/usr/bin/php")) {
        error_log("~ ScriptAt: Could not locate /usr/bin/php");
        return false;
    }

    $fullcmd = "/usr/bin/php -f $cmd";

    $r = popen("/usr/bin/at $time", "w");
    if (!$r) {
        error_log("~ ScriptAt: unable to open pipe for AT command");
        return false;
    }
    fwrite($r, $fullcmd);
    pclose($r);

    error_log("~ ScriptAt: cmd=${cmd} time=${time}");

    return true;
}
```